# Showing favicon on page in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, favicon

I have a page whereby a user uploads a favicon (.ico) icon, and then I show the icon to the user embedded on the page.  To do this, I am using the typical image tag  with the path to the .ico file.

This works perfectly fine in Chrome & Firefox, however in IE I am getting a broken image symbol instead of the .ico.

Has anyone ever encountered this issue?  I know that usually you need to use the link tag  to show the favicon near the address bar, however I need to show a preview to the user before actually the user saving.  I cannot seem to find any information online on how to show the favicon in an image tag on IE.

Thanks

**EDIT**: 
I am using IE11, not sure if this issue is just for this version.

Comment: convert it to .png or .jpg - it's the shortest way.

Comment: @AndrewEvt  i know about that option too, however I am not sure how to do that.  Cos basically I am asking the user to upload the icon and then showing it in a page directly.  I am not sure if I can make use of a service or some library to do the conversion in between :/

Comment: ok, can you show the code, that uploads file and shows it on the page?

Comment: @AndrewEvt Please  share your code.!

Comment: @AndrewEvt  the code as such is a normal HTML form and on pressing submit it saves the path to the image in the database.  Then it does a page reload and updates the image source with the path of the uploaded .ico image.  Nothing out of the ordinary.